# Alternatives to hard coding values in stored procedures SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: function, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, range

I want to avoid modifying stored procedures when users request to add/remove numbers (1, 2, 5, etc.).  I thought about adding data table that would hold these values.

Issue with data table:  Individual numbers work great with data table, but when I'm dealing with a range of numbers, I am not able to figure out ideal solution for it that is easy to maintain and great performance.

Example of account numbers in where clause:

- Between 0 and 39000
- Between 80000 and 80299
- 46000 (add only one number)
- 2801  (add only one number)

Example of my WHERE Clause:

```
WHERE
(
Account.Account  BETWEEN  '00000'  AND  '39999'
OR Account.Account BETWEEN '80000' AND  '80299'
OR Account.Account IN ('46000')
OR Account.Account IN ('02801')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a question. Can your conditions change? By condition I mean the whole condition not only the numbers. Depending on the answer you have two cases:

#### Case 1: Your condition does not change. Only numbers do

like:

```
WHERE
(
Account.Account  BETWEEN  '00500'  AND  '00578'
OR Account.Account BETWEEN '80000' AND  '80299'
OR Account.Account IN ('00700')
OR Account.Account IN ('08534')
)
```

In such a case you can pass this numbers as parameters as below

```
WHERE
(
Account.Account  BETWEEN  @lowerlimit1  AND  @upperlimit1
OR Account.Account BETWEEN @lowerlimit2  AND  @upperlimit2
OR Account.Account IN (@case1)
OR Account.Account IN (@case2)
)
```

#### Case 2: Your condition does change

like:

```
WHERE
(
Account.Account  BETWEEN  '00500'  AND  '00578'
OR Account.Account IN ('08534')
)
```

in this case the best option is to create a configuration table with the numbers given in the condition as below

```
WHERE
(
Account.Account IN (SELECT Numbers FROM ConfigurationTable)
)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I edited my question.  Let me know if you have additional question or need more detail.

Comment: Edited my answer!. Let me know if it is usefull